# My text rotates but the background-image does not

Tags: html, css

I am creating a vertical menu and I can get my text rotated the correct way but my image (a vertical image) seems to be horizontal.

Want I have:

[image]

Want I want:

[image]

**CSS Code:**

```
.menu {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;

transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
writing-mode: rl-tb;

background-image:url('button.jpg');
width: 61px;
height: 205px;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fffde5;
font-family: Gobold;
font-size: 30pt;
}

a:hover {
color: #338bb0;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="menu-box">
    <a class="menu" href="#" >HOME</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >MYSELF</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >CONTACT ME</a>        
</div>
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? I don't know what the problem is. The solution provided below does not turn the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use This css this will work

```
.menu {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;

transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
writing-mode: rl-tb;

background-image:url('button.jpg');
width: auto; /*Changed*/
height: 61px; /*Changed*/
}
```

Comment: I didn't see it at first but it seems that the image isn't rotating at all but just repeating it self.